# Arcobjects- IAnnotateLayerPropertiesCollection2.QueryItem in Python

Tags: python, arcobjects, labeling

Anyone tried access label properties trough ArcObjects with Python?

I try to obtain reference to label object with IAnnotateLayerPropertiesCollection2.QueryItem, but when I do:

```
pA = pGLyr.AnnotationProperties
new = NewObj(esriCarto.LabelEngineLayerProperties,esriCarto.IAnnotateLayerProperties)
pA.QueryItem(0,new)
```

I get:
*Runtime error : call takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)*

I'm not sure where is the error comming from.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In comtypes, *out* arguments are returned as a tuple, they do not need to be passed in to the function. From the [comtypes home page](http://starship.python.net/crew/theller/comtypes/#calling-methods):

> **Calling methods**
>
> Calling COM methods is straightforward just like with other Python
>   objects. They can be called with positional and named arguments.
>
> Arguments marked `[out]` or `[out, retval]` in the IDL are returned from a
>   sucessful method call, in a tuple if there is more than one. If no
>   `[out]` or `[out, retval]` arguments are present, the `HRESULT` returned by
>   the method call is returned. When `[out]` or `[out, retval]` arguments are
>   returned from a sucessful call, the `HRESULT` value is lost.
>
> If the COM method call fails, a `COMError` exception is raised,
>   containing the `HRESULT` value.

This works for me:

```
def enumerate_anno_properties(layer):
    gfl = CType(layer, esriCarto.IGeoFeatureLayer)
    if gfl:
        annoProps = gfl.AnnotationProperties
        for i in range(annoProps.Count):
            yield (CType(annoProps, esriCarto.IAnnotateLayerPropertiesCollection2)
                .QueryItem(i))[0]
```

Comment: Cool, works great. I would not think of generator use.